# Loop a function with specific condition

Tags: linux, unix, expect

I have a function:

```
set timeout 20
set f [open "password.txt"]
set password [read $f]
close $f

spawn ssh user@example.net -p 724
expect "user@example.net's password:"
send $password
interact
```

in the `password.txt` I have only 1 word

After running this script using expect in terminal I have the access to the server if that single word that exist there is the right one.

I have 2 problems:

SOLVED---------1)I want to loop the execution of this script in such a way that in case I will have 2,5,100 words in `password.txt` the script will try all of them for password, not only the first one as it is now.

2)If I will manage to loop the execution of the function using all words from the 
`password.txt`, I need to make on if statement that will solve this issue(after 3 attempts to write the password server disconnects you so you need to connect again after each 3 attempts.)

Update: the server answer after first 2 attempts like this `Permission denied, please try again.` after the last attempt (3th one) it's says `Permission denied (publickey,password).` and it throw's me to my normal command line state.

I am trying to do something like

```
while read line
 do
  echo "Trying: $line"
  echo ssh user@example.net -p 724 --password "$line" ## NOT REAL CODE
 done < password.txt
```

but have no idea how to implement this logic in the expect syntax.

Till now I managed to write this

```
set timeout 20
set f [open "password.txt" r]
set password [read $f]
close $f

foreach i $password {
puts "trying this as a pass : $i"
spawn ssh user@example.net -p 724
expect "user@example.net's password:"
send $i
interact
}
```

It solves me first problem but the bug is that I need to press manaul "enter" after the server asks for the password. And after I hit "enter" the script tries  first word from the list, then if it's wrong one again I need to press "enter" and the script will try the second word from the list.

How can I simulate pressing "enter" in the script?

Comment: Glad  you're getting there. (Delete your comments, they will just confuse people). IMHO the stuff at the top, while interesting background, just obscures your real question. 2. It may be possible to to this, but you may spend a lot of time working out out to do it. 3, What's wrong with just `while read pswd ; do if ! ssh .... $pswd  cmds .... 2>&1 | grep "your success string" ; then echo matched on pswd=$pswd ; exit 0 ; fi ; done < pswdfile` , just using `bash` or `ksh`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I am trying to understand your code, it's pretty hard explanation for the solution. Thank you

Comment: I am saying, don't use `expect`. Just clean  up your `bash` p-code as it is very close to what your need. The only difference is that restarts `ssh` for each password in the file, until it finds one that works. Take my code, and put it into properly indented form. You will see the logic. (I may have missed a big of syntax, but it shouldn't be hard to figure out).

Comment: @shellter what dose ssh .... and cmds .... means  in stead of .... what should i write. Thank you.

Comment: Almost like you have written in your p-code ... `ssh user@example.net -p 724 --password "$pswd" `. The `cmds` is the command you want to execute on the remote machine. If you just want to see that you have a connection, you can just put `ls -l` instead of `cmds ....` I have to leave, so you'll have to experiment. Use the shell debug/trace option `set -vx` (turn off with `set +vx`) to see how variables are being interpreted. Don't get confused that you see single quotes `'` where you didn't put them in the trace output, that is just a display feature of the trace mode. Good luck!

Comment: @shellter ok, Thank you

Comment: my security-sense is tingling: why are you brute-forcing login attempts?

Comment: @glennjackman I am currently taking an Information Security course, and we have a task to attack a server under certain conditions